# UseState hook dont make the second argument as setter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

using useState() hook in react 18 and running the application, my browser in the console tells me that the setters that I created using it are not functions

```
const AdminPanel = () => {
    const {brandVisible,SetBrandVisible} = useState(false)
    const {typeVisible,SetTypeVisible} = useState(false)
    const {dyeVisible,SetDyeVisible} = useState(false)
    return (
      <Container className="d-flex flex-column">
        <Button variant={"outline-dark"} onClick={()=> SetTypeVisible(true)} className="mt-2 p-1">Добавить тип</Button>
        <Button variant={"outline-dark"} onClick={()=> SetBrandVisible(true)} className="mt-2 p-1">Добавить производителя</Button>
        <Button variant={"outline-dark"} onClick={()=> SetDyeVisible(true)} className="mt-2 p-1">Добавить краску</Button>
        <CreateBrand show={brandVisible} onHide={()=> SetBrandVisible(false)}/>
        <CreateDye show={dyeVisible} onHide={()=> SetDyeVisible(false)}/>
        <CreateType show={typeVisible} onHide={()=> SetTypeVisible(false)}/>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

after reading this hook, I realized that I used it correctly

Comment: `[]` instead of `{}`

Comment: useState return's and array ,which consists value and setter

    const [brandVisible,SetBrandVisible] = useState(false)

Comment: *"after reading this hook, I realized that I used it correctly"* - The error you were seeing was telling you otherwise, and it's usually right about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

#### Wrong

```
const {brandVisible,SetBrandVisible} = useState(false)
```

#### Correct

```
const [brandVisible,SetBrandVisible] = useState(false)
```